# Text rendering techniques for games

Tags: fonts, text, signed-distance-field

I'm researching text rendering techniques for 3D applications, and I'm having a hard time finding information on the topic. Do you know of any other methods of text rendering that are actually used in current games or have a historical significance?

So far I have:

- Using prerendered bitmaps of glyphs / strings as textures,
- converting the glyph vectors to triangle meshes and rendering it as such,
- signed distance fields (popularized by [Valve's paper](https://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf)),
- [GLyphy](http://code.google.com/p/glyphy/).

I haven't managed to find anything else though.

Does anyone know what large engines, such as Source, Unreal, Unity, etc. use?

Sources would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, textures with glyphs and 2D polygons are probably what 99% of the games out there are using today. You might have a few niche cases where the game devs want more accuracy/resolution, then you can find stuff like the distance fields or [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). But that's about it, AFAIK.  Sorry, no sources to back this up either :P

Comment: Ah, yes, btw Nvidia once had the [NV_path_rendering](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering) OpenGL extension, but I think they've dropped it a while back...

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Resolution independent curve rendering using programmable graphics hardware](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1073303) from Microsoft Research presented at SIGGRAPH '05. Paper is available for [download](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/loopblinn05.pdf). Some information is also availble online at [GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html). I don't know if this method has been used in any games.